# Makefile : last resort match anything pattern

Tags: makefile

According to the [GNU make guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match), "The rules you write take precedence over those that are built in. Note however, that a rule whose prerequisites actually exist or are mentioned always takes priority over a rule with prerequisites that must be made by chaining other implicit rules."

So I wrote this testing makefile to do a little experiment (GNUmakefile is the name of this testing makefile) :

```
% :: 
        @echo "last resort implicit rule is working"

.DEFAULT_GOAL = src/hello.o

src/hello.o : 
GNUmakefile : ;#used to prevent remaking this makefile, although in this case it is unnecessary.
```

My file organization is illustrated as the following :

```
GNUmakefile(#ordinary file)

src(#directory)
    ----hello.c(#ordinary file)
```

I was expecting it to output `"last resort implicit rule is working"`, since `src/hello.o` will match the target pattern `% ::` and this is a terminal match anything implicit rule. According to the Implicit rule search algorithm specified in [GNU make guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html#Implicit-Rule-Search), this rule should apply.

However, when I run `make` , it output `cc    -c -o src/hello.o src/hello.c`.

I figured out that in fact `src/hello.o` was matched against the built-in implicit rule. When I run `make -r` , it output `"last resort implicit rule is working"`. And the output of `make -d` attested this.

But I think this behavior is contradicting what is specified in GUN make guide.
Can anyone help?

By the way, I read the last resort rule in [GUN make guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Last-Resort.html#Last-Resort), it says "So such a rule’s recipe is used for all targets and prerequisites that have no recipe of their own and for which no other implicit rule applies.". Is this the solution to my question? I doubt that, because I think this depends on whether last resort rule is defined and where the last resort rule is defined because orders matters when searching for implicit rule using the algorithm specified in [GNU make guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html#Implicit-Rule-Search).

Comment: Comments : There are time when more than one target pattern matches the target and GNU make uses the "best fit" algorithm to figure out which rule to be used. What is worth thinking is that , if a user defined pattern rule and an built-in implicit rule both matches the target, which rule will be used? In this case, does "best fit algorithm" dominates over the "precedenced" user defined pattern rule(implicit rule)?

Comment: Comments2 : I perused the sentence "So such a rule’s recipe is used for all targets and prerequisites that have no recipe of their own and for which no other implicit rule applies.". Is "no other" the key to the solution of my question here? I don't know if this is a issue between "best fit" algorithm and "precedenced" user defined pattern rules, or this is just a trait of last resort match anything pattern rule.

Comment: A few things -- first, you can edit your question, and put your comments in there.   Second I've heard that making a catch-all rule (`%:`) is _really_ bad for performance on larger makefiles.  It's better to use the `.DEFAULT:` target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine with some ancient make at my workplace...

> ```
> [teve@madar mktest]$ tree
> .
> ├── GNUmakefile
> └── src
>     └── hello.c
>
> 1 directory, 2 files
> [teve@madar mktest]$ cat GNUmakefile
> % ::
>         @echo "last resort implicit rule is working"
>
> .DEFAULT_GOAL = src/hello.o
>
> src/hello.o :
> GNUmakefile : ;#blablabla
> [teve@madar mktest]$ make
> last resort implicit rule is working
> [teve@madar mktest]$ make --version
> GNU Make 3.81
> [...]
> ```

... and it does not work with one-step less ancient make:

> ```
> [teve@madar mktest]$ make
> cc    -c -o src/hello.o src/hello.c
> [gergelyc@sauron mktest]$ make --version
> GNU Make 3.82
> [...]
> ```

Given that the current versions are 4.x, I feel super lucky to have exactly these two versions with the behaviour-change.
I tried to look at occurrences of `implicit`, `built`, `order`, `last` and `match` in a [changelog](https://github.com/pololu/make/blob/master/ChangeLog) ending with 3.82, but I have not found anything obvious.
Canceling the built-in rule with an empty `%o : %c` works, by the way.

Comment: Thanks! I will try these version of GNU make later. Your answer reminds me that the `::=` operation is also not supported in my version of make.

Comment: My make version is exactly `GNU make 3.8.2 Build for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu`.

Comment: @Han mine is the very same actually (x86_64 and RedHat), just I have not included that part. This applies to the 3.81 too (that is on another machine)